# small & readable scheme interpreter in C++?

Tags: c++, scheme

Anyone know of a good / small scheme interpreter in C++? Perferably something < 2000 LOC, with a simple garbage collectro (either compacting or mark & sweep), no need to support all of R5RS, just basics of if/lambda/set!/cons/car/cdr and some basic operations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Well, there's a [veeery tiny lisp](http://www.civilized.com/getlisp.html) by Gary Knott. Not even close to R5RS, but it's small, and *comes with a book describing the internals!* However, it's C, not C++, and as far as I can remember there's no GC (but I could be wrong).

There's also [Mini Scheme](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/~nmh/t3x.org/zzz/) by Nils Holm, but it's also C, and a bit larger than what you asked (2404 lines of C plus 1352 of Scheme). Nils has also written [Scheme 9 from Empty Space](http://t3x.org/s9fes/), which is larger but also comes with a book describing every piece of code.

[Tinyscheme](http://tinyscheme.sourceforge.net) is another small Scheme (4500 lines of C plus 452 of Lisp)...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a long list of scheme implementations:

http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations

Several of them are embeddable interpreters, mostly in C.  That shouldn't be a deal breaker for C++.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [Scheme Implementations](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/imp.html) doesn't organize based on such practical criteria. :)

I did find one [Scheme Interpreter in C++](http://networks.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amitabha/code.html) that you might check out to see if it fits your needs.  I haven't tried this particular one, so this isn't an endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Gambit Scheme.   It's also written in C and has the advantage that it's designed to be embeddable.   I have personally used it to [embed Scheme inside Excel 2003](http://www.hackinghat.com/index.php/lisp/the-excel-gambit)!

Although it's very much work in progress it works fine and you could easily adapt it to whatever C++ needs you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a project at my university to do exactly this. [Shaka Scheme](https://github.com/uhmanoa-transpiler-project/shaka-scheme) is an attempt to implement R7RS in C++.

We are working towards implementing macros and continuations as of the time of writing, and will focus on an implementation model after [R. Kent Dybvig's dissertation's heap-allocated model for evaluation](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/3imp.pdf).

In the future, we hope to have a fully-comprehensible documentation database through the GitHub wiki of our design and methodology to make implementation of Scheme readable to novices.