# Data structure for storing variables, functions, arrays and types

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, interpreter

I am writing an interpreter for a statically typed language I have created. The interpreter is being made in C. For the sake of simplicity, I will list only two basic data types, int and float.

I need a struct of some kind which can store:

- a basic data type
- a function returning a type
- an array of one some type
- a type definition

types can simply be one of the basic data types or an array or function. Therefor it is valid to have a function returning a function returning a function returning an int.

I know I can store basic data types using a union, but how to store functions, arrays and type declarations I do not know.

Comment: There are whole books written about this topic.  I would maybe get some ideas by looking at the source of other interpreted language, such as Python,

Comment: Could you explain what "statically typed" means to you? Do you have [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)? How? (that should go into your question). Explain  a bit more what your programming language looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) then [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces). They cover quite well your questions.

You may also want to read [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) and the [*Dragon Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition)

An essential notion is that of [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). You need to have them (if you want first-class function values and higher-level functions).

Notice that a type declaration is mostly a source code thing. You want [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST), perhaps as simple as [s-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). You could have a [symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table), or could have first-class [symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)) (starting with [interned strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)).

You don't want plain `union`-s like in C, but [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) or sum types. You certainly want a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). You could use [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Look for simple [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language))-like interpreters, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642584/841108). Study [SIOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIOD).

Study the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) interpreters, e.g. [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

in objective-c all objects (not primitives like int) are basically a struct where the first object is a pointer to a metaobject called isa so something like (this is simplified without meta object just a type indicator int):

```
typedef struct{
    int isa;
    int intVal;
    float floatVal;
} ObjectType;

#define INT_TYPE 1
#define FLOAT_TYPE 2

ObjectType * newObject(int type, int intVal, float floatVal)
{
     ObjectType * r = calloc(sizeof(ObjectType *),1);
     r->isa=type;
     if (type == INT_TYPE)
     {
         r->intVal=intVal;
     }else if (type == FLOAT_TYPE)
     {
         r->floatVal=floatVal
     }else{
          free(r);
          return NULL;
     }
     return r;
}
```

then make a getter for float and int... that would be a pretty simple start.

Comment: How does that answers the question?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is an object type that can hold an int or a float

Comment: this can only hold int and float, not arrays, functions etc